# How to subset datasets in Mathematica 10

Tags: dataset, subset

I'm sorry if this is obvious but I can't find a way to select only a certain amount of columns of a dataset (or delete a certain amount of columns from a dataset) using the key of each column.

I basically want to reproduce something similar to the following R code:

```
new_dataset <- subset(initial_dataset, select = c("key1", "key5", "key7"))
```

which then returns only columns 1, 5 and 7 using the name of the column (for the sake of this example simply named "key1", "key5", and "key7"

Comment: I think you can simply select certain columns from the whole matrix m. Something like this: m2=m[[1;;3,All]].

Comment: @ChenStatsYu If m is a matrix that would be m[[All,1;;3]]. You're selecting rows instead of columns.

Comment: I meant the data structure `Dataset`. It's all good now, with `KeyDrop[]` it works fine. However, overall I'm still not convinced of how Mathematica handles those `Dataset` structures, for example, at least in version 10.0.1.0 it seems impossible to change the value of an element of a data set. I also have no idea how to create a Dataset from the columns rather than rows. (so let's say we have 5 vectors, and want those 5 vectors to be the columns of a dataset).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, you are right. I was only thinking about an example, did not pay too much to the details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out of the documentation for `Dataset`, it's easy:
[image]

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I should have had a better read of the documentation. I was more trying to figure out how to drop a specific column using the keys as well. Is it possible to just Delete or Drop a single column of a data set using the Key name?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyDrop.html

Comment: Brilliant thanks!

Comment: On a related matter, is that possible to name both the rows and column? See http://i.stack.imgur.com/okt9w.png for example. I read the doc, it looks like that the `Dataset` only takes "column"? In my example, I want to be able to extract rows as well, say dataset["B1997"] as well as dataset["Bin"]. Is that possible?